# хлебные крошки в поисковой выдаче

Tags: seo

Есть какой то способ сделать разметку на сайте чтобы поисковик (яндекс, гугл) сформировал такой сниппет ?

Знаю что это можно сделать с помощью "хлебных крошек", а что это такое и как их сделать на сайте не пойму.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эти крошки как следы до самого последнего пункта. По аналогии, когда на ходу хлебные крошки сыплются по траектории движения. На странице можно объявить линки на другие документы с помощью тега `link`. Если задать атрибуту `rel` этого тэга значения `prev` или `next`, то можно догадаться что за чем следует. Вероятно гоогль по этому атрибуту и рисует хлебные крошки

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте применить разметку структурированными данными для **[BreadcrumbList](https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList)** :

```html
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses">
    <span itemprop="name">Dresses</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
  </li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope
      itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/dresses/real">
    <span itemprop="name">Real Dresses</span></a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

На указанной ссылке/странице также есть варианты для **[RDFa](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-syntax/)** + **[JSON-LD](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Пример к комментарию

p1.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="next" type="text/html" href="p2.html"/>
    <title>laboard</title>
  </head>
...
```

p2.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="prev" type="text/html" href="p1.html"/>
    <link rel="next" type="text/html" href="p3.html"/>
    <title>Россия</title>
  </head>
...
```

p3.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="prev" type="text/html" href="p2.html"/>
    <link rel="next" type="text/html" href="p4.html"/>
    <title>Москва</title>
  </head>
...
```

И т.д. в том же духе

Comment: Вы трактуете данные атрибуты **абсолютно неверно**. Их нужно использовать исключительно для страниц, разбитых на множество частей. Допустим, если вы пишете форум, то вы вряд ли станете все сообщения держать на одной странице - вы воспользуетесь пагинацией, и вот тут-то понадобятся `rel="next"` и `rel="prev"`, чтобы связать между собой страницы обсуждения. В справке Google подробно [разжевали](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=ru) применение этих атрибутов.

Comment: @terron Либо у нас гуголь разный, либо я дурак, либо одно из двух, но мой гуголь по Вашей разжованной ссылке трактует абсолютно так же как и я. Так что не надо тут воду мутить.